# Android :scrollview not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a xml(`registerpage.xml`) file and I declared that in a `ScrollView` so that its scrolling smoothly up and down and I deleted the parent view of this XML.

When I did like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
    android:id="@+id/regsrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <include android:id="@+id/registrationlayout" 
             layout="@layout/registerpage"/>
</ScrollView>
```

the above code I have written in main.xml and deleted the  parentview of `registerpage.xml`. now the problem is `registerpage.xml` is not scrolling as before and the softkeypad is disturbing. Now I want to give the controls to the `registerpage.xml` in activity so that it will scroll up and down(wit some velocity)

How to do this?

Thanks in advance...!